# Custom Devise gem user profile works great, but caused errors for signup, edit, ... [Rails 5]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I added user profile to Devise from some tutorials I found online and linking to profile works great. However now I'm having problem with **user signup**.

I assume, since I have created **users_controller.rb** for user profile, it is looking into users_controller.rb now for all actions. So, regarding the sign up, I added **create** def, then it asked **def new**, then **def update** and so on... Things got really complicated and I got different type of errors!

**MY QUESTION:**
Is it possible to redirect all actions to the default Devise signup, login, update, ... while I keep user_controllers.rb only for user profile?

Thank you!

route

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

  root 'posts#index'
end
```

Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

[image]

[image: user_controller.rb]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Routing and Controllers in Devise

Your `config/routes.rb` determines the actions triggered with each `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH` request made to `urls`

You can read more about this at the following link
[Routing/Controller in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

When you configure **Devise** you set the routes by using the `devise_for` method in your `routes.rb`

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
end
```

to read more about the method `devise_for` read the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for)

`devise_for` will generate the following routes:

```
# Session routes for Authenticatable (default)
     new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                    {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"new"}
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in                    {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"create"}
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out                   {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"destroy"}

# Password routes for Recoverable, if User model has :recoverable configured
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"new"}
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"edit"}
        user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)         {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"update"}
                      POST   /users/password(.:format)         {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"create"}

# Confirmation routes for Confirmable, if User model has :confirmable configured
new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"new"}
    user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"show"}
                      POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {controller:"devise/confirmations", action:"create"}
```

If the client/browser performs a `GET` request to the server via the url `/users/sign_in`, the server will execute the **action new** from the controller in the folder `app/controllers/devise/sessions`

That is where my views are generated and even if I do not have the devise controller, this is how it is mapped.

You can override this behavior, as explained in this [guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers), bu using the following syntax:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

This means that for `sessions` you are going to use the controller located in the folder `app/controllers/users/sessions` and not `devise/sessions`.

You can test this, generate your routes and see how you will have the routes for every action.

### The Best Practice

The best practice as suggested from [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) is just generating the devise controller, which will have actions that are already wired with the Devise routing. Each action from the controller will call with `super`  the Devise controller actions, if you want to enhance or change that logic you can do it by reading the [**Devise** API](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise)

To that controller you can add any action you want then configure appropriately your routing

For routing and controller info from ruby on rails guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Fabrizio  So **devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/' }** should redirect to the default devise **controllers/users/**, no?

Comment: @Designer `devise_for :users` redirects to the default devise controller. You don't have the devise controller in your `/app/controllers`, you can generate a controller that makes a call `super` to the **devise controller**. The devise controller is in your gem, you can check it out in the **github** page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise and it will be in your GEMFILEs. You can find it there in the **RVM** or **Rbenv** folder depending on what you use

Comment: @Designer `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/', registrations: 'users/', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/', passwords: 'users/' }` etc-era keep adding the controllers from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise to this routing, but this is the wrong way to do this. You should enhance the standard devise controller as defined hear https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers you can better understand devise code from http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/index and you should check their controller